# How to change background color of submenu of multi level accordion menu inside a nav element by using the javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, accordion, multi-level

My Html code makes a UL list with LI element and UL list is inside the NAV  tag in html code.

I want to change the background color of all link. for this I want any JS (javascript) which can take all LI element inside UL element inside of nav element as per code requirement above.

Please lookup the mentioned ids as

id="sidemenu" , id="accordionSideMenu"

how I can using these id of div and ul tag both in javascript so i can change the background color of UL List.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You're getting downvoted because you haven't included any HTML or JS you've attempted to your question. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see a) that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first, and b) used a [mcve] to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

to do this just use css selector in js. Using JQUERY

```
$("#sidemenu ul").css("background-color", "black");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have asked one question here before sometime that how we can change the style sheet on runtime for a specific component styling by external CSS file in code.

The change was required for multi level menu as horizontal navigation bar.

I had tried by so many resources but didn't get success.

After few days, I got one resource in youtube and got the success.

I am putting the code here as solution.

HTML code:

```
<head>
<link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
<script>
function swapStyleSheet(sheet){
    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}
</script>
</head>




<body>
<h2>Javascript Change StyleSheet Without Page Reload</h2>
<button onclick="swapStyleSheet('dark.css')">Dark Style Sheet</button>
<button onclick="swapStyleSheet('blue.css')">Blue Style Sheet</button>
<button onclick="swapStyleSheet('default.css')">Default Style Sheet</button>
</body>
```

---

dark.css code:

h2{
font-size:40px;
color: black
}

---

default.css code

h2{
font-size:35px;
color: green

### }

blue.css code

h2{
font-size:30px;
color: blue

### }

As I read, in Bootstrap we can do by single scss file but I am newbee in bootstrap.

I hope, this little code will be useful.